# Adding text on the border of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm struggling with tricky issue here.

Basically I'm trying to locate text in the middle of the line surrounding linear layout, as per image:

[click to see image (sorry, I only joined StOv and don't have enough reputation to post images directly)](http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=35ivyit&s=5)

One of the solutions I had in mind was to create background style for the layout with blue line offsetted from the edges (red border), and place on top of it (padding-ed accurately from the left edge) text with opaque background of the same colour as background (green border):

[click to see image (sorry, I only joined StOv and don't have enough reputation to post images directly)](http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2n0scd2&s=5)

That should work, but solution itself seems to be bit provisional. Can you guys think of smoother, cleaner way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a background image as u need. Set it to background property of ur layout it will work